# Laravel can not display images

Tags: php, laravel

I have a script where user can upload photo with client id. Photo is in `storage/app/public` and name of file in db. Then I get name and try to display photo or file, but I can't.
Here's my code:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('storage/app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Here is controller:

```
public function file($id)
{
    $client = Client::findOrFail($id);
    return View::make('file', compact('client'));
}
```

file.blade.php

```
<img src="{{ public_path($file_name) }}" />
```

And console log:

[image]

How Can I display files?

Comment: How do you determine the value of `$file_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have created symbolic link from storage to public.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

You can access Storage urls like this to display image:

```
<img src="{{ url('/') . Storage::url($file_name) }}">
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: What should be here? FULLY_QUALIFIED_PATH @Waleed

Answer (score 0):

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the `public` disk uses the local driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Also need to do `Storage::disk("public")->url($file_name)` to get the file URL

Comment: And i got "The public/storage already exist". Again don't know what to do

Comment: @BartoszRowiński Yes in the blade view check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#retrieving-files under file URLs. In general you should read the docs they're well written and simple.